# SSRS Hidden footer occupying space

Tags: reporting-services, footer, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I'm working on a SSRS report which has different formats for the first page and the overflow pages. The first page has a large footer that shouldn't be displayed on the overflow pages. I'm hiding it using an expression on current page number but it still occupies space. The body on overflow pages does not span the whole page and leaves a large blank space at the bottom. Is there any way to solve this?

Thanks in advance,
Sumit

Answer (score 2):

There is not a good way to hide that empty space(As far I know. I did lot of research when I stuck with this issue.).But if you are showing footer only on the first page then add the footer content on the report content part and then set it's visibility depending  on the page number. That way you are showing the footer content on first page only. And if you are repeating that page footer on last page that also works depending on condition and it doesn't occupy the empty space on the page.

Comment: This is what I'm doing. Added the footer part on report, added expression for hidden property. But when it is hidden also, there is a space as big as the footer left at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Dont add your content on footer part but on the main central content part of the report

Comment: How do I do that? Format of the report I'm trying to create can be found at [link](http://www.gsa.gov/portal/forms/download/115462) and [link](http://www.gsa.gov/portal/forms/download/115466). Former is the 1st page and the other one is the overflow sheet(s). The controls below the tablix have to go into the footer as they have to be displayed on 1st page even if the tablix overflows to next page.

Comment: Then I guess you have to fix the number of rows in your tablix for each page with footer content.

Comment: I currently solved this by splitting my report into 2. 1st page in one design and the rest in another. I'm having to split the transactions through code. Not the most elegant way but it works for now. Looking for a way to combine pdf's if possible.